# large file through WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, large-data-volumes

Similar questions are flowing around and I looked at all of them. It appears none solve my issue.

**-- UPDATE: --**

I am trying to upload a document (pdf, doc, or whatever) to a database using WCF Service.
The call to the service looks like this:

```
using (var cw = new WCFClientWrapper<ICommonService>())
{
    cw.Channel.DocumentInsert(content, filename, contentType);
}
```

Here is signature for the contract:

```
[OperationContract]
void DocumentInsert(byte[] content, string fileName, string contentType);
```

Please note that I am passing byte array for the content as this is what needs to be passed to store things in DB.

**-- End of Update --**

I can successfully upload a small file (couple kb). However, when I try to upload something larger (20kb), I get an Exception:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'DocumentInsert'. The maximum array length quota (16384) has been
>   exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by
>   changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
>   object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 31774.

The error seems to be obvious... just go and increase the MaxArrayLength. I have done that without any successful result. Below are the relevant parts from my web.configs

**Client:**

```xml
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureBehavior">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_Service" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="262144" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://dev.svc.someurl.com/CommonService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_Service"
                behaviorConfiguration="SecureBehavior"
                contract="MyApp.Contracts.ServiceContracts.ICommonService"
                name="MyApp.Contracts.ServiceContracts.ICommonService">
      </endpoint>
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Service:**

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="MyApp.WCFServices.CommonService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding"
                  contract="MyApp.Contracts.ServiceContracts.ICommonService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service name="MyApp.WCFServices.AccountService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="MyBasicHttpBinding"
                  contract="MyApp.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IAccountService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Attaching diagnostics shows:**

- **Construct Service**: no errors/warnings
- **Open Service**: warning - Configuration evaluation context not found - No matching  tag was found. Default endpoints added.
- **Listen at 'http://dev.svc.someurl.com/CommonService.svc'** : no
  errors/warnings
- **Processing message 1** : no errors/warnings
- **Processing Action 'http://tempuri.org/ICommonService/DocumentInsert'.**
  : throws exception that I wrote at the very beginning.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have came across with the same exception a few months ago. To send/receive large data to/from WCF service you have to set `transferMode="Streamed"`. When use transfermode as Buffered, it actually puts the entire file in memory before uploading/downloading. Therefore a large buffer is required on both the web client and the WCF service host.Whereas Streamed transfers can improve the scalability of a service by eliminating the need for large memory buffers. For more information on transfermode, see the MSDN article on [TransferMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Didn't help though. It looks to me that it just ignores my binding and uses a default one. I'm not sure why or how though

Answer (score 0):

All right, after a day of struggling I finally found an issue.
I just had to make sure that the name of the  tag in WCF web.config matches the namespace and the name of the service:

```xml
<service name="ServicesImplementation.WcfServices.CommonService">
```

Unfortunately it was not something that you guys would see based on the information that I provided.